# Determining if a Subgroup $H$ is Normal in $G$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

[image]

What's wrong with my answers?

The first $2$ groups are abelian. So every subgroup $H$ will be normal in $G$.

$D_6=\{a,b|a^6=b^2=e, bab=a^{-1}\}, <a^{21}>=\{e,a^{3}\}$. Which is Normal in $G$ since $xHx^{-1}\subseteq H$, $\forall x\in G$

$<a^{21}b>=\{e,a^3b\}$. Which is not Normal in $G$ since $xHx^{-1}\subseteq H$, is not true $\forall x\in G$. For example, take $x=a^2$. Same reason for $<a^{21},b>$

$-j$ does not commute and neither do upper triangular matrices.

Comment: That an element $x$ in a group $G$ does not commute with everything in $G$ is irrelevant to the question of whether the subgroup generated by $x$ is normal in $G$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I mean an element $h\in H$. Since to be Normal we must have $xh=hx$, $\forall x\in G$

Comment: @BoratSagdiyev You don't need $xh = hx$ for all $x$, you need $xH = Hx$ for all $x\in G$. This means that $xh$ need not be $hx$, but can be $h'x$ for some other element $h'\in H$.

Comment: This is a very common mistake. $xH=Hx$ must not be confused with $xh=hx$. The former is what a normal subgroup is all about, the latter is a different concept altogether (I think it's called the centralizer).

Comment: @Stahl Oh, I see. Would an equivalent definition be $xhx^{-1}\in H$, $\forall x\in G$ and $h\in H$? So by that definition, $<-j>$ is Normal but upper triangular matrices aren't since $ABA^{-1}$ is not necessarily upper triangular if $A\in GL_2(Q)$. Is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In  $Q_8$, $-j$ has order $4$, which means the subgroup $\langle -j\rangle$ has index $2$. Any subgroup of index $2$ is normal.

Actually, it is easy  to see every subgroup of $Q_8$ is normal.

In $\operatorname{GL}_n(\mathbf Q)$, the subgroup of upper triangular matrices is *not* normal: this would mean any matrix similar to an upper triangular matrix is upper triangular. In particular  any diagonalisable matrix with non-zero eigenvalues would be upper triangular!

Comment: Thanks. For the other parts, is it correct to say that $<a^{21}>$ is Normal, $<a^{21}b>$ isn't, and neither is $<a^{21},b>$?

Comment: Oh! yes, perfectly correct. I didn't mention them, because I thought you were sure for the first questions.