# Determining the Order of Quotient Groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

[image]

What's wrong with these answers?

For $\mathbb Z_{28}/<24>$, We can see that $<24>=<4>$. Let $a\in \mathbb Z_{28}$, then by Euclidean division we have $a=4q+r$ for some $0\le r\lt 4$. So $a+<4>=r+4q+<4>=r+<4>$ for $0\le r\lt 4$ (4 possible values).

For $U(31)/<15>$, $31$ is prime so $15$ is a generator with $<15>=U(31)$. Therefore, $|U(31)/<15>|=1$

For $D_4/<a>$, we have $<a>=\{e,a,a^2,a^3\}$ so for all Rotations $R$, $R<a>=<a>$ but for reflections $F$, $F<a>$ will be a distinct left coset (4 in total). Same reasoning for $Q_8/<i>$

Comment: Unless you tell how is defined **your** $\;D_4\;$ it is going to be hard to guess what's going on there. One of the most usual sets of name for the generators of dihedrals groups is $\;\{s,t\}\;$ , so what is your $\;a\;$ ?

Comment: The first one is correct. I did not check the second, but your argument is nowhere close to complete. The final two are way off, as you have given answers that do not even divide the order of the group.

Comment: The first two are correct. The third I can't tell as I cannot guess, and the fourth, assuming $\;Q_8\;$ is the quaternions group (of order eight) is then obviously false as $\;7\,\nmid\,8\;$ .

Comment: @DonAntonio If you use s and t for the generators, I would assume you use the Coxeter presentation (which seems to not be used that much in introductory courses).

Comment: @DonAntonio $D_4$ is the dihedral group of order $8$. $D_4=<a,b|a^4=b^2=e, bab^{-1}=a^{-1}>$

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft No. In fact the presentations with involutions is not what I was thinking about, but the more usual, standard one: $\;s^2=t^n=1\;,\;\;sts=t^{-1}\;$ and etc.

Comment: @BoratSagdiyev Then your last two are way off as they show orders that don't even divide the group's

Comment: Ah, I see. I've now found that $|D_4/<a>|=2$ using the multiplication table in $D_4$. Do you have any hints for the last one though? it seems to me that all the left cosets are distinct except for $i<i>=e<i>$?

Comment: Note that $15^{10} \equiv 1 \bmod 31$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the last case, every subgroup of $Q_8$ is normal, $i$ has order $4$ since $i^2=-1$. Hence $Q_8/\langle i\rangle$ has order $2$.

For the second case you have to justify that $15$ is a generator: non-zero elements in a prime field are not all primitive elements.

Comment: The fact that every subgroup of $Q_8$ is normal is not really relevant to the question. I mean, it is necessary for the question to even make sense, but I don't see how it helps with the answer.

Comment: $|<15>|=10$ and $|U(31)|=30$. But how can I figure out which of the $30$ possible cosets are equal?

Comment: You mean how to group elements by triads in the same cosets mod $15$?

Comment: @Bernard I'm not familiar with triads. I just mean that there are $30$ possible left cosets. But how do I know whether these cosets are distinct so I can find the order of the Quotient group $U(31)/<15>$?

Comment: You already have it : $\lvert G/N\rvert=\dfrac{\lvert G\rvert}{\lvert N\rvert}$ for any finite group $G$  and any subgroup $N$. ‘Triad’ is just a personal phrasing to say there are $3$ cosets. I thought you wanted  to find the list of elements in each coset.

Comment: Oh, silly me. I forgot that theorem and tried to find the order directly from the number of distinct cosets. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Bernard By the way, can you help me figure out if a subgroup $H$ is normal in $G$? http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2022151/determining-if-a-subgroup-h-is-normal-in-g

Comment: @Borat Sagdiyev: I've posted an answer to your other question.